# Are there any equivalent of Heavy Job plugin in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have different jobs running on our jenkins. Some jobs are heavy and taking a lot of CPU and RAM, some are not. So I would like to have some plugins to help me set the weight for those jobs, just like https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin.

But since we are using Jenkins pipeline which is not supported by Heavy Job plugin (See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41940). Is there any other equivalent for pipeline jobs just like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as flexible as a dynamic weight, but to avoid overload you can create several executors with a different label (such as many with label `light` and only a few with label `heavy`) and then use `node` to [target these labels](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node).

This is not a solution to the packing problem, only prevents too many jobs with a `heavy` class from running at the same time.